# Rotate around the origin of coordinates in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, rotating

I use **rotate** command in Tikz to rotate graphics around the origin. However, this does not work when I substitute coordinates with references.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.05]
% frame
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);   \coordinate (H) at (120:50);
\coordinate (S) at (-50,0); \coordinate (D) at (30,0);
\coordinate (D1) at (30,-15); \coordinate (D2) at (30,15);

\begin{scope}[rotate=60]
    \filldraw[fill=red] (S) circle [radius=0.5];    % source
    \foreach \y in {-10,...,9}
    {
        \draw (D) ++(0,\y*1.5) rectangle +(1.5,1.5);
    }
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \fill[green!20] (S) -- (D1) -- (D2) -- cycle; %projection
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{scope}

\node [very thin,draw=blue!80!black,label=above left:orbit,circle through=(H)] (Or) at (O) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When I remove the references and use coordinates directly, Tikz performs well.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.05]
\coordinate (X-) at (-60,0); \coordinate [label=right:$x$] (X+) at (60,0);
\coordinate (Y-) at (0,-60); \coordinate [label=left:$y$] (Y+) at (0,60);
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);   \coordinate (H) at (120:50);
\draw[->,help lines] (X-) -- (X+);
\draw[->,help lines] (Y-) -- (Y+);
\begin{scope}[rotate=60]
    \filldraw[fill=red] (-50,0) circle [radius=0.5];    % source
    \foreach \y in {-10,...,9}
    {
        \draw (30,0) ++(0,\y*1.5) rectangle +(1.5,1.5);
    }
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \fill[green!20] (-50,0) -- (30,-15) -- (30,15) -- cycle; %projection
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{scope}

\node [very thin,draw=blue!80!black,label=above left:orbit,circle through=(H)] (Or) at (O) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So what's wrong with my first code?

Comment: All those coordinates are outside the scope. Hence the rotate operation is not effective on them (they are not rotated). Now you draw some thing with reference to those, you won't get rotation too. Put all those `\coordinate` definitions inside the scope and see what happens.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

As Harish Kumar said, this should produce the desired output:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.05]
% frame

\begin{scope}[rotate=60]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);   
    \coordinate (H) at (120:50);
    \coordinate (D) at (30,0);
    \coordinate (S) at (-50,0); 
    \coordinate (D1) at (30,-15); 
    \coordinate (D2) at (30,15);


    \filldraw[fill=red] (S) circle [radius=0.5];    % source
    \foreach \y in {-10,...,9}
    {
        \draw (D) ++(0,\y*1.5) rectangle +(1.5,1.5);
    }
\end{scope}

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \fill[green!20] (S) -- (D1) -- (D2) -- cycle; %projection
    \end{pgfonlayer}

%\node [very thin,draw=blue!80!black,label=above left:orbit,circle through=(H)] (Or) at (O) {};
\node [very thin,draw=blue!80!black,label={[rotate=60]above left:orbit},circle through=(H)] (Or) at (O) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can rotate the cancas:

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \pgflowlevel{\pgftransformrotate{60}}  
        \fill[green!20] (S) -- (D1) -- (D2) -- cycle; %projection
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

[image]

Comment: You have to put `\node [very thin,draw=blue!80!black,label=above left:orbit,circle through=(H)] (Or) at (O) {};` inside the `scope` too.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference, but you can use: `\node [very thin,draw=blue!80!black,label={[rotate=60]above left:orbit},circle through=(H)] (Or) at (O) {};`

Comment: Sure it does. That small red circle's center will not lie on the big circle.

Comment: You're right, sorry!